# How to fix Cobertura inconsistent Code Coverage issue for Java Project which use Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, cobertura

I am using Cobertura Gradle Plugin for My Java Project to generate code coverage report. Cobertura was giving consistent reports on my windows machine but when I run the same build on Jenkins server and publish the report on SonarQube using a sonar scanner then I can see an inconsistent coverage report. Each build was giving different coverage percentages.

Cobertura Version: 2.1.1
Cobertura Gradle Plugin Version: 'net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.2'
Java Version : 1.7 
Gradle Version : 3.5

I have tried to debug gradle build in info mode and found classNotFoundException while intrumenting in the logs so i have tried to add all dependencies manually using auxillaryClasspath setting of gradle cobertura plugin but no success.

**Cobertura.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'http://central.maven.org/maven2/' }
    mavenLocal()
    dependencies.classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2',
                           'oro:oro:2.0.8',
                           'org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1',
                           'org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.1',
                           'org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.0.1',
                           'org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1',
                           'org.ow2.asm:asm-util:5.0.1',
                           'net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.2'
  }
}

apply plugin: net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaPlugin

def jobpath = new File(buildDir.toString() + "/reports/cobertura")
cobertura {
  coverageFormats = ['html', 'xml']
  coverageReportDir = jobpath
}
test.finalizedBy(project.tasks.cobertura)
```

**Main build.gradle**  part of the file is pasted here

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'cobertura.gradle'
...
...
test {
  forkEvery = 2
  maxParallelForks = 4
  maxHeapSize = "2048m"
  afterTest { TestDescriptor td, TestResult tr ->
    println "${tr} ${td}"
  }
}
....
...
dependencies{
...
..
}
```

Coverage Percentage on Windows machine was 85 % and consistent so the same needs to be reflected on the Jenkins Server report as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to analyze the cobertura logs by running the gradle build with **"--info"** command and found out that while intrumenting cobertura was writing 349 classes but while generating report it was loading random number of classes. But on my Windows machine it was saving and loading same number of classes i.e. 349.

**Build Logs on Jenkins Server:**
`15:17:27  04:47:27.782 [INFO] [net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler] Cobertura: Saved information on 349 classes`
...
`15:18:14  04:48:14.326 [INFO] [net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler] Cobertura: Loaded information on 181 classes`

**Build Logs on Windows Laptop:**
`14:30:25.745 [INFO] [net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler] Cobertura: Saved information on 349 classes`
...
`14:31:58.940 [INFO] [net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.CoverageDataFileHandler] Cobertura: Loaded information on 349 classes.`

I have checked cobertura issue list and found the concurrency issue while writing cobertura.ser file. https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/342

Workaround was to remove parrellel forks while running test cases.

As we were using **maxParallelForks = 4** in our main **build.gradle**, parallel executors were corrupting the .ser file.

I have removed **maxParallelForks = 4** from the test task as by default it will use 1 and Jenkins Server has started giving the same coverage as of windows machine.

Our Jenkins server is a powerful machine with Multi-Core processors and I think that is the reason parallel fork was working on Jenkins and giving us the above issue.